# NativeScript - unit testing an HttpInterceptor NSLocationStrategy error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, nativescript, angular-http-interceptors

I'm writing an app with NativeScript 6.4.1 and Angular 8.

I want to write unit tests for my HttpInterceptor. My interceptor adds on a token to select http calls and routes users to an authentication page if they get certain errors from the backend.

The code runs fine and it works but my unit test does not.

When I run my unit test, I get this error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RouterExtensions -> NSLocationStrategy]:
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterExtensions -> NSLocationStrategy]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NSLocationStrategy!
error properties: Object({ originalStack: 'Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for NSLocationStrategy!
    at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SelfServiceApp/files/app/vendor.js:157861:33)
```

I don't know why I am getting the error.

Here is my unit test:

```
import { nsTestBedBeforeEach } from 'nativescript-angular/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpInterceptorService } from '~/app/core/interceptors/http-interceptor-service';
import { HttpLoaderService } from '~/app/core/shared/http-loader.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from '~/app/authentication/shared/services/authentication.service';
import { SsoAuthenticationService } from '~/app/authentication/pages/single-sign-on/sso-authentication.service';
import { EndpointHelperService } from '~/app/core/shared/endpoint-helper.service';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';

import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule, Location } from '@angular/common';

describe('HttpInterceptorService Test', () => {

    let service: HttpInterceptorService;

    beforeEach(nsTestBedBeforeEach([], [
        HttpInterceptorService,
        HttpLoaderService,
        AuthenticationService,
        SsoAuthenticationService,
        EndpointHelperService,
        RouterExtensions
    ], [
        HttpClientTestingModule, 
        RouterTestingModule, 
        NativeScriptRouterModule, 
        CommonModule
    ]));

    it('should be defined', () => {
        service = TestBed.get(HttpInterceptorService);
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Here is my interceptor:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError, from } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpLoaderService } from '../shared/http-loader.service';
import { boundMethod } from 'autobind-decorator';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../authentication/shared/services/authentication.service';
import { SsoAuthenticationService } from '../../authentication/pages/single-sign-on/sso-authentication.service';
import { EndpointHelperService } from '../shared/endpoint-helper.service';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private httpLoaderService: HttpLoaderService,
        private authentication: AuthenticationService,
        private ssoAuthentication: SsoAuthenticationService,
        private endpointHelper: EndpointHelperService,
        private router: RouterExtensions
    ) {}

    public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.httpLoaderService.onRequestStart();

        // do not add to token endpoints
        if (this.endpointHelper.isTokenEndpoint(request.url)) {
            return this.returnRequest(request, next);
        }

        //do not add to registration server
        if (this.endpointHelper.isRegisterEndpoint(request.url)) {
            return this.returnRequest(request, next);
        }

        return this.appendSSOTokenToHeader(request, next);
    }

    @boundMethod
    private appendSSOTokenToHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

        return from(this.ssoAuthentication.getHttpHeader())
            .pipe(
                switchMap((newHeader) => {

                    request = request.clone({ 
                        body: { ...request.body, clientcode: this.authentication.clientcode },
                        setHeaders: { Authorization: newHeader },
                        url: this.authentication.mobileApiUrl + request.url
                    });

                    return this.returnRequest(request, next);
                })
            );
    }

    @boundMethod
    private returnRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next
            .handle(request)
            .pipe(tap(this.handleSuccess), catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    @boundMethod
    private handleSuccess(event: HttpEvent<any>): void {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.httpLoaderService.onRequestEnd();
        }
    }

    @boundMethod
    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

        this.httpLoaderService.onRequestEnd();

        if (this.endpointHelper.shouldRedirectToSSOPage(error)) {
            this.router.navigate(['register-via-sso']);
        }

        return throwError(error);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot([])` instead of `NativeScriptRouterModule`.

Comment: I there, it worked! This should be an answer with some explanation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load `NativeScriptRouterModule` as `NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot([])`, it's similar to loading router in your app module with available routes. Since it's unit test, you wouldn't pass in routes here.